# migration not rolling back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollback, rails-migrations

I had run this migration:

```
class AddUniqueToLocationColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :locations, :name
    add_index :locations, :name, unique: true
  end
end
```

And now I am trying to rollback but its showing error:

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
> canceled:  remove_index is only reversible if given a :column option.

how can I roll back this migration to my previous version?

Comment: Try changing it to `remove_index :locations, column: :name`

Comment: I think now you have to remove the indexes for location and name manually from within your migration using the remove_index method. For this you can create new migration or change to up and down state.

Comment: Thanks a lot max. It worked. Just had to specify "column: :name" instead of only "name" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly define up and down:

```
class AddUniqueToLocationColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_index :locations, column: :name
    add_index :locations, :name, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :locations, column: :name # remove unique index
    add_index :locations, :name # adds just index, without unique
  end
end
```

Comment: It still wont work..max's solution worked. Just had to change ":name" to "column: :name". :) and i edited my code according to your code. So both helped ;)